# NODE - Something else is already running on port

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have an app with node for the backend and react for the front. I have an npm development script running concurrently on my server `package.json` like so:

```
"server": "nodemon server.js",
"client": "npm start --prefix client",
"watch:sass": "npm run watch:sass --prefix client",
"dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\" \"npm run watch:sass\""
```

This was working perfectly for the whole time up until I was ready to deploy and I ran my `react-scripts build` under my client folder `package.json`.

My server listens on port 3000 and I setup my react-sripts with a proxy like so: `"proxy": "http://localhost:8000"`.

After my react build whenever I try to run `npm run dev` I get the following error: `Something is already running on port 3000`.

Yes, I have tried to list and see all processes running on that port with `sudo lsof -i:3000` and yes I have tried to `killall node` processes.

I have tried to change the port on either `app.listen()` or change the `react-scripts start` TO `PORT=3001 react-scripts start` and ***YES*** this will get rid of my initial problem but the problem is then that I cannot seem to get my front to communicate with the back and all my API calls will not work.

```
Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/users/login from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:8000.
See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNREFUSED).
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

there should be another node process still alive using that port, try executing `pkill node` in your terminal and then launch your sever again

Comment: Doesn't help :(

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kill-port) is a handy tool to kill something running on a node port:

```
npm install --global kill-port
```

then

```
kill-port --port 8080
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for being silly. I set the proxy to port 8000 but kept the port on app.listen() to 3000 when it should've been 8000!